# Dynamically change dockerrun.aws.json image tag on deploy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to dynamically get the version tag from my `__init__.py` file and append it to the dockerrun.aws.json image name for example::

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "dockerkey",
    "Key": "mydockercfg"
  },
  "Image": {
    "Name": "comp/app:{{version}}",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "80"
    }
  ]
}
```

This when when I do `eb deploy` it will build the correct version. At the moment I have to keep modifying the json file with each deploy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also stumbled upon that last year, where AWS support stated there's no such feature at hand. I ended up writing a script that receives the docker tag as parameter and composes the dockerrun.aws.json file on the fly with the correct tagname.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Tal - how did you integrate this dynamic dockerrun file? Is it checked in to source control or can AWS provide a hook of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a bash script which runs

```sh
eb deploy
```

Before it executes that command I change a symlink depending on if I'm running production or staging. For Example:

```sh
ln -sf ../ebs/Dockerrun.aws.$deploy_type.json ../ebs/Dockerrun.aws.json
```